# Reference a cell by looking at a number in another cell

Tags: google-sheets

Cell A1 has "200" in it. I want to use that "200" when I reference another cell.

For example: `='TestSheet'!A200`

Instead of typing 200 above, I want it to point at cell A1 for the value. Something like `='TestSheet'!A&A1` , but that does not work.

Comment: hmm, you can point to cell A1 like `='TestSheet'!A1`?

Answer (score 1):

Point to cell A1

```
='TestSheet'!A1
```

fix row 1 and change column A->... according

```
='TestSheet'!A$1
```

fix column A and change row 1 ->... according

```
='TestSheet'!$A1
```

fix all column and row A1

```
='TestSheet'!$A$1
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `INDIRECT` and `ADDRESS`.  In whichever cell you are using, put the formula:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(A1,x))
```

x is the column as a number and can also be referenced to another cell.